# Additional logic to jboss realm

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, post-processing, security-constraint

Current setup of application is JSF with JBoss server. I would like to include additional logic along to existing realm authetication which navigates to login failed page. Looking for something that invalidate successful pricinpal from Realm(java).

Scenario: User typed correct password and login but there are certain condition which does not allow him to login.

Configurations:

standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="login">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="sufficient">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/datasource"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="query"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="query"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="???"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="???"/>
            <module-option name="principalClass" value="org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
   <security-domain>login</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>login-error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I had few ideas which I don't see very easy despite an easy change.

- Remove pricipal from session and set parameter that is checked on login page (single login page only)
- Write custom realm login module

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your additional checks involve a database query in the same database as that accessible through `java:/datasource` then maybe all you need is a more sophisticated query for the `principalsQuery`.

Alternatively, you could implement a servlet filter which executes the additional logic. If the test fails and the user should not be provided access then you call [HttpServletRequest.logout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout--) and then redirect to the login-error.html page.

However, it may be more elegant to do this by modifying your `security-domain` configuration and adding a second login module that contains your additional logic:

```
<security-domain name="login">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database"
                      flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/datasource"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="query"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="query"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="???"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="???"/>
            <module-option name="principalClass" value="org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="com.yourorg.yourapp.ExtendedLoginCheck"
                      flag="required"
                      module="name-of-wildfly-module-containing-ExtendedLoginCheck">
            <module-option name="your module option" value="your module option value" />
            ...
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

where `com.yourorg.yourapp.ExtendedLoginCheck` implements [javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html). Note the `login-module` `flag` attribute value has changed to `required`. These modules get executed one after the other and both must succeed for the authentication attempt to succeed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks